# Building a math expression parser/evaluator?

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to build my own math expression parser in Java ,I know that there are many script managing engines out there.But I wanted to build my own ,just for parcticing.

However, I've been finding difficulties in progressing. so I began to think if there is a better way of writing it. Here is how I am doing it:

(in the meantime I'm assuming that the input is legal)
The only legal operators are:  +  -  *  /  ^  (  )

I get a String expression input from the user. Then I start looping throgh the string input to seek "(" if I found one I calculate the value of the value inside it then replace the sub expression string with the result.

Should I continue to program it this way or should I take another approach? 
Are there any tutorials that explain how to accomplish this (not the code - just the theory in general)?

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Personally, I think it's silly to roll your own, but if you insist you should take a look at a working parser to see how it works and use what you learn to build your own.  I'd recommend you take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  This will at least teach you how to write your own grammars.  ANTLR will generate a parser based on your grammar file and then you can use the parser in may different ways.  The generated parser may give you some insight on how you might want to roll your own.  Good luck!

Comment: It's a nice exercise, but you should starts only supporting `+ - * /` - after you have this part [working](http://alfasin.com/a-simple-calculator-in-ruby/), you can plan how to extend it to support power and brackets.

Comment: @JNYRanger: Learning is never silly, and writing a parser is a great way to gain a better understanding of programming languages. I'm not sure I would recommend reading the output of a parser generator; it tends to be rather human-unfriendly...

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset You are absolutely correct, learning is never silly.  However, re-inventing the wheel tends to be useless, but if it's for educational purposes then yeah, it isn't pointless.  Normally, I'd agree about a parser generator being human-unfriendly, but ANTLR's output is oddly elegant for generated code if you're using a simple grammar (such as in OP's question)

Comment: @JNYRanger: Interesting, I should apparently check out ANTLR some time. (Of course, if this were for some production system, I agree that parser generators is the way to go, but it doesn't look like that from the question.)

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which allows you to parse algebraic expressions including operator precedence and parentheses.

Also, you might be interested in [Abstract Syntax Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) to represent the result of the parsed expression, on which you can do further work, as pretty printing and evaluating the expression.

Comment: If you are doing this for education, I'd recommend both, but start with the Abstract Syntax Tree approach. The Shunting Yard Algorithm builds and implied Abstract Syntax Tree, and while you are learning it may be easier for you to debug/reason about if you can see the explicit tree and compare it to what you would expect. It's also dang cool to put in the debug statements that allow you to watch the tree being built and then consumed.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to make a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), which is the standard way to parse reasonably simple languages. Essentially, it's a more structured way of implementing the "search for parenthesis and evaluate expression inside it" approach that you are describing. Make sure that you are comfortable with recursion before you start, though.